# Animating the present and dismiss of a Share Extension with custom UI on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm developing a Share Extension for iOS 8 with custom UI, but it appears without animation, how can I do this? It's a regular UIViewController.

Also, it appears on fullscreen on iPad and I want it to be a modal view controller, that appears in the center of the screen and doesn't fit it, how can I do this?

Regards.

Comment: Can you provide some details on the appearance animation you'd like to put in place?

Comment: I can't speak for Alvaro, but in my case I just want the "normal" form view/modal presentation. Note that you don't have access to the presenting view controller so you can't use some of the new transition controller stuff.

Comment: What I'm currently doing is leaving a BlankViewController as initial, which has a clear background, and then on viewDidAppear, I present my main view controller with the animation I prefer.

Comment: can you explain how implement custom view instead of default share dialog? i try for that but i cant do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is the cleanest solution I found so far to animate my custom view controller in and out!

Animate IN:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Dismiss:

```
- (void)dismiss
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.20 animations:^
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of animating the `UIViewController`'s `view`, I am suggesting a bit different approach.

I have created a dummy `UIViewController` (called `PresentingViewController` here on) whose `view.backgroundColor` is set to `[UIColor clearColor]`. I then present the intended custom `UIViewController` modally (or custom animation if you like) on top.

This is the code for the `PresentingViewController`:

```
@implementation PresentingViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PresentController" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PresentController"]) {
    CustomViewController *controller = (CustomViewController *)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
    controller.context = self.extensionContext;
  }
}

- (IBAction)unwindFromShareVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Cancelled" code:0 userInfo:nil];
    [self.extensionContext cancelRequestWithError:error];
  }];
}

@end
```

Notes:

1. `extensionContext` is set only on the `PresentingViewController` and thus it is required to be passed on to the `CustomViewController`.
2. For animating dismiss, I was unable to use an unwind segue, because it was difficult to know the completion of dismissal. So I used [dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) instead.